# Are there any free apps for Ubuntu that convert `.wav` files to `.cda` for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, media

Are there any free apps for Ubuntu that convert `.wav` files to `.cda` for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brasero

```
aptitude install brasero
```